# Getting an error on XSL-FO template parsing to create PDF?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm looking for a solution and how to resolve the issue while parsing an XML data to PDF file through XSL-FO template language. I'm having trouble to find out the exact cause of the issue while user trying to download the data as a PDF format.
My exception as follows:

```
"org.apache.fop.events.loggingeventlistener processevent rendered page"
```

Thank you in advance, I know this is a pretty generic question, but really I wanted to know the root cause for the same.

My XML:

```
  <root>
<name>shyam</name>
<friend>
    <name>Abc</name>
    <phNo>90909090909</phNo>
    <age>32</age>
    <closefriends>
        <names>test123</names>
    </closefriends>
</friend>
<friend>
    <name>Xyz</name>
    <phNo>32323232323</phNo>
    <age>44</age>
    <closefriends>
        <names>test345</names>
    </closefriends>
</friend>
</root>
```

My XSL-FO:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block>Hello,
          <xsl:value-of select="name" />!</fo:block>
        <fo:block>
          <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
              <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>
                    No.
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>
                    Name
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>
                    Phone Number
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
              <xsl:for-each select="./friend">
                <xsl:for-each select="./closefriends">
                  <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                      <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                      <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="names" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                      <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="phNo" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>
          </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

I have added my XML and XSL-FO for your reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is not a *something-went-wrong* kind of exception, just a *here-is-something-interesting* exception :-).

More seriously, it's an `INFO` level logging message that tells you that a page was created:

```
19-lug-2016 17.36.32 org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
INFO: Rendered page #1.
...
```

While processing large files it is an useful indication that FOP is still working as expected and not just stuck in an endless loop.

FOP's website has a page about these [feedback messages](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/events.html#consumer), with examples of how to programmatically handle them (if you need to); otherwise, you can just ignore them.

*(disclosure: I'm a FOP developer, though not very active nowadays)*

Comment: Do you mean to say that..Issue is with XSL-FO template is going on endless loop or something else from back-end...?

Comment: @Maniram No, what I'm saying is that there is **nothing wrong at all** _if_ the only messages you see are like `INFO: Rendered page #1`. I tried running your example (adding some missing lines in the included stylesheet, which is not well-formed) and the PDF output is created with just a few warnings about _fonts_ and the _automatic table layout_ (which FOP does not support yet, falling back to equal-sized columns if no other indication is provided in the FO file). **If you don't get the PDF, please edit the answer to include all the output messages.**